# triggerCommand with argument in irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I want to trigger a command with an argument from another command, and also trigger a command with an argument from a controller, so my command solutions of command are:

```
class ChangeLanguageCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string Command Name
     */
    protected $name = 'change_language';

    /**
     * @var string Command Description
     */
    protected $description = 'Change Language,Change language of bot';

    protected $pattern = '{lang}';
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if($this->getArguments())
        {
            $args = $this->getArguments();
            if($args['lang'])
                $lang=$args['lang'];
            else
                $lang='fa';
        }
        else
            $lang='fa';

        if($lang=='fa')
        {
            $response=$this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'زبان ربات تغییر یافت.']);
            $this->triggerCommand('start',$this->getArguments());

        }
        else
        {
            $response=$this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Robot language changed.']);
            $this->triggerCommand('start',$this->getArguments());
        }


    }
}
```

and my command solutions of controller is:

```
class TelegramBotController extends Controller
{
    public function commandHandlerWebHook()
    {
        try
        {
            Telegram::addCommands([
                Telegram\Bot\Commands\HelpCommand::class,
                App\Telegram\Commands\StartCommand::class,
                App\Telegram\Commands\ChangeLanguageCommand::class,
                App\Telegram\Commands\ThingsToSendAdvertCommand::class,
                App\Telegram\Commands\LuggageSpaceAdvertCommand::class,
            ]);
            $commandsHandler = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
            $update =Telegram::getWebhookUpdate(['timeout' => 120]);
  
                $chat_id = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
                $data=$update["message"]["text"];
                switch ($data) {
                    case 'تغییر زبان':
                        $command = "change_language";
                        $arguments =['fa'];
                        $res = Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute($command, $arguments, $commandsHandler);
                        break;
                    case 'Change Language':
                        $command = "change_language";
                        $arguments =['en'];
                        $res = Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute($command, $arguments, $commandsHandler);
                        break;
                    case 'راهنما':
                        $command = "help";
                        $arguments =[];
                        $res = Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute($command, $arguments, $commandsHandler);
                        break;
                    case 'Help':
                        $command = "help";
                        $arguments =[];
                        $res = Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute($command, $arguments, $commandsHandler);
                        break;
      
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

But it does not work and I do not get any answer from the bot(bot return 200 status).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

At irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk version 3.4 you should use update as second parameters.

```
$update = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
//...
triggerCommand('start', $update)
//Or
Telegram::getCommandBus()->execute('start', $update, [])
```